# Join multiple FK values in one table

Tags: join, foreign-keys

I'm writing some access queries and I'd like some help on a particular query. I'm still very new to SQL. Here is a simplified version of my tables:

```
Project Details
---------------
projectID (PK)
projectStartDate
projectEndDate
projectName
managerID (FK)
leadID (FK)
coleadID (FK)


Employee
--------
empID (PK)
empName
```

The managerID, leadID, and coleadID all correspond to an empID. I'd like to retrieve the Project Details table, but replace the IDs with the names of the employees. I've successfully been able to do this for one FK at a time using an inner join, but can't figure out a way to accomplish this for all roles.

It would also be nice to be able to change the attribute names on the results to managerName, leadName, and coleadName.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same way, you probably have done it for one ID:

```
SELECT pd.*
     , emp_m.empName ManagerName
     , emp_l.empName LeadName
     , emp_c.empName ColeadName
  FROM ProjectDetails pd
     , Employee emp_m
     , Employee emp_l
     , Employee emp_c
 WHERE pd.managerID = emp_m.empID(+)
   AND pd.leadID    = emp_l.empID(+)
   AND pd.coleadID  = emp_c.empID(+)
```

The `(+)` is for an outer join, so it will select all records of the `ProjectDetails` table, no matter if it can match the manager, lead or colead.

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something wrong. After I run this I only get one project returning.

Comment: Okay, i changed them to left joins in my answer. This should work properly.